# Sequelize query where createdAt date like today date

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

In Express framework I am using Sequelize. I want select user's first name and last who are registered a specific date match with createdAt field. My query is in below.

```
const userData = models.users;
var querystring = { where: {createdAt: {[op.like]: '%2018-09-27%'}}, attributes: ['first_name', 'last_name'] }
userData.findOne(querystring).then(function (userData) {

    console.log(userData);

});
```

But I got error below....

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments: 
>   [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: %2018-09-27%, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the date range query who are registered on a date.

use startTime = start of the day, endTime = end of the Day.

```
Model.findAll({
    where: {
        createdAt: {
            $gt: startTime,
            $lt: endTime
        }
    }
})
```